# Calculating time difference in python

Tags: python, datetime, duration, timedelta

I want to make a code in python to find out the duration an employee had worked by taking two inputs.

- `input1` will be the time when the employee *arrived* at work, in `hh:mm` format.
- `input2` will be the time when the employee *left* work, in `hh:mm` format.

I want to calculate the duration an employee worked in `hh:mm` format when I subtract `input1` from `input2`.

Please help in making this code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn’t working about the approaches you’ve taken?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `timedelta` attribute for time objects.

You can use a `datetime` object first, then do:

```py
difference = datetime1 - datetime2
```

The, finally, do:

```py
print(difference.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Alternatively, if you are only allowed to use time input/object, you can do:

```py
import datetime
# Time in example
a = datetime.time(9, 30)
# Time out example
b = datetime.time(17, 45)

hours = abs(int(b.strftime('%H')) - int(a.strftime('%H')))
minutes = abs(int(b.strftime('%M')) - int(a.strftime('%M')))

time_difference = datetime.time(hours, minutes)

print(time_difference)
```

Comment: [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) has no method strftime either